# Storing Highscores using PlayerPrefs in Unity

Tags: unity, c#

```
int highscore = 0;
void Update()
{
    storepoints();
    print(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highscore", highscore));
}
void storepoints()
{
    if (points>highscore)
    {
        highscore = points;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("highscore", highscore);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }

}
```

Using the following code:

it works first time. But not the second time

so, for e.g, when I play the first time, suppose my score is 2, my high score becomes 2. However when I play the second time, and my score is 1. My high score becomes 1. This shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely forget to update the highscore before checking it the second time:

```
int highscore = 0;
void Update()
{
    storepoints();
    print(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highscore", highscore));
}
void storepoints()
{
    highscore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highscore", highscore); // ADD THIS LINE

    if (points>highscore)
    {
        highscore = points;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("highscore", highscore);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The highscore field starts off as 0 so any points over 0 will count as a highscore and write over the score stored in PlayerPrefs. Set highscore to the PlayerPrefs value before calling storepoints.

You could do this in a start method:

```
void Start () {
     highscore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highscore", highscore);
}
```